# Swift generic class initializer

Tags: swift

I found a problem with designing result class in swift

```
struct Result<T>{
    private let data: T?
    let error: NSError?
    var isSuccess: Bool {
        get {
            return data != nil
        }
    }

    init(data: T) {
        self.data = data
        self.error = nil
    }

    init(error: NSError) {
        self.data = nil
        self.error = error
    }
}
```

Usage should look like this

```
Result(data: "something") // T as string
```

The problem occurs when I want to pass an error

```
Result(error: errorFromSomewhere) //T is not specified
```

Below is real application usage:

```
class ParseRegistrationProvider: RegistrationProvider {
    func register(model: RegistrationForm) -> Promise<Result<String>> {
        return Promise { accept, reject in
            let user = PFUser()
            user.username = model.nickName
            user.password = model.password
            user.email = model.emailAdreess
            user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock({ (isSuccess, error) -> Void in
                if isSuccess {
                    accept(Result(data: "OK"))
                } else {
                    var errorResult = Result(error: error!) //causes error
                    reject(errorResult)
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

"errorResult" causes compiler error:

> Generic parameter T could not be inferred

Update:
this approch works correctly:

```
Result<String>(error: errorFromSomewhere)
```

Comment: What is the context in which you see the error? (Based on the error message, it seems unrelated to this struct specifically and more related to the context in which it is used).

Comment: @nhgrif I've updated the question.

Comment: You also changed the compiler error message.  What happens in that same context when you initialize as `Result<String>(error: error!)` and what is the signature of the `reject()` function?  What argument type does it expect?

Comment: `let res = Result<String>(error: errorFromSomewhere)` *does* compile. – A small *self-contained* example which does not use external libraries would be helpful.

Comment: Or `let res: Result<String> = Result(error: errorFromSomewhere)`?

Comment: Yeah Its my bad. I found that reject func doesn't require Result<T> thats why it wasn't working. Nevertheless xcode hints misled me. Problem is solved.

Comment: Note that this is not a good way to build `Result`. There's been tons of work on `Result` within the Swift community (see https://github.com/antitypical/Result for a very nice one). If you're going to build your own (which is totally fine; I do it all the time) you want it to be an enum, not a struct.

Comment: @RobNapier thanks for that approach!

Comment: @razor118 It would be better to post a self-answer than to edit in an update.

Comment: @nhgrif I will do as you suggest

Comment: @razor118 in the current form your question is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to suggest to use variant type for Result like this cause it is more compact and can be used in pattern matching naturally:

```
enum Result<T>{
    case Data(T?)
    case Error(NSError)
    var isSuccess: Bool{
        get{
            switch self{
            case .Data(_?):
                return true
            default:
                return false
            }
          }
    } }
```

Your code may become like this:

```
class ParseRegistrationProvider: RegistrationProvider {
    func register(model: RegistrationForm) -> Promise<Result<String>> {
        return Promise { accept, reject in
            let user = PFUser()
            user.username = model.nickName
            user.password = model.password
            user.email = model.emailAdreess
            user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock({ (isSuccess, error) -> Void in
                if isSuccess {
                    accept(Result<String>.Data("OK"))
                } else {
                    var errorResult = Result<String>(error: error!) //causes error
                    reject(errorResult)
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

When you use classes instead of structs, you can define one base class (e.g. `ErrorResult` with `init(error: NSError)`) and one derived `Result<T>`) with `init(data: T)`).

This way, you entirely side-step the generic parameter.
However, you potentially add some run-time overhead because of using a class.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question directly, you could just declare errorResult as:

```
var errorResult : Result<String>
```

That would fix the problem immediately.
However, I think the better solution is to use an enum instead of a struct as it is more appropriate (unless there is more to it than you posted).

```
enum Result<T> {
    case Data(T)
    case Error(NSError)

    var success : Bool {
        switch self {
        case .Data:
            return true
        case .Error:
            return false
        }
    }
}
```